# Unity Warning: Ignoring depth surface load action as it is memoryless

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting 2 warnings in Unity when trying to make screenshot:

```
Ignoring depth surface load action as it is memoryless
Ignoring depth surface store action as it is memoryless
```

I have found this [thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ignoring-depth-surface-store-action-as-it-is-memoryless.817068/) but it is referencing to Unity Remote which I am not using.

Basic code to reproduce the warning:

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
   // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {
    StartCoroutine(TakeScreenshotUI());
  }

  public IEnumerator TakeScreenshotUI()
  {
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    var tex = ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture();
  }
}
```

I am getting same warnings in Unity 2019.2 and 2020.1.2.

Can someone help me figure out what the problem is?

UPDATE: warning is appearing only on MacOS with Metal Graphic API

Comment: I'm getting the same error but there is another problem which might be linked with it. In my 2D game touch is not working on device. @David Ndckr have you found any solution?

Comment: Yes and no, @M.ShuaibImran, I have found out that this warning is happening only on Mac and with Graphic API sets for Metal (Project Setting / Player / Other Settings ). Using OpenGLCore as Graphic API is prevent the warning when making scrrenshots in game. Unfortunately  it is crashing whole system instead on a random occasion when I am in editor mode. So this is not solution for me.

Answer (score -2):

Unity spits out a lot of warnings. I would just ignore them if your code is working.